# Jackson 2.0 compatibility with Jackson 1.x annotations?

Tags: json, jackson, backwards-compatibility

I have an older framework class that is annotated with jackson 1.x. My application uses jackson 2.0 to handle json serialization. Is it possible to configure jackson 2.0 to understand the "old" annotations? currently these annotations are simply ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box configuration, but it should be quite easy to implement Jackson 2.0 AnnotationIntrospector (possibly extending `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`) and make it use Jackson 1.x annotations in addition to or instead of 2.x annotations.

In fact, you could basically just take 1.x `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and replace its usage.

The reason 2.0 does not and will not support 1.x annotations directly is that it would pull in additional dependencies, and probably cause version conflicts. But that does not prevent external libraries from doing this -- in fact, if anyone wanted to contribute, I am sure Jackson project would accept "Jackson 1.x annotations" module for github.

Comment: Hey, I am facing same type of Error, My Project is spring 1.5.10 Based which is using Jackson 2.9 and I have made my Rest service layer with this version, Now I added a new Dependency kie-server-client which is using 1.9 version of jakson and I get NoSuchMethod Errors for java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.with(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector;)

It means new dependency is failed to work with jakson 1.9 which is already present in classpath. How can I make my project to work with both?

Comment: @Mubasher No, that is not related in any way to 1.x / 2.x difference. Classes live in different packages so this error is strictly for 2.x. But you do have some version mismatch between 2.x minor versions: some component is older than others, and missing a method added in a later minor version.