# Parsing Jackson annotations with Swagger

Tags: json, rest, jackson, swagger, api-doc

By default, Swagger parses a class's data members in order to document the objects used as parameters or returned by a given web service. If you're using Jackson, the Jackson annotations provide a much more accurate description of the API.

Does anyone know an (easy) way to get Swagger to parse Jackson annotations. Perhaps an overridden parser?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would help, but Jackson 2.1 and later expose POJO structure as seen by Jackson itself (`ObjectMapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor`), which could be used for generating different kinds of artifacts. I have written an Avro schema generator with it, for example (as part of [Jackson Avro module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-avro))

Comment: Wow, this could be a great solution. Unfortunately, we're using Jackson 1.9 ... I'll have to see how difficult it is to upgrade. Any hints beyond [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461760/jackson-2-0-compatibility-with-jackson-1-x-annotations)?

Comment: Changes are mostly mechanical really, and with IDE what I did was to remove old imports, and start replacing with new to solve majority of compilation problems, then moving to remainders. But maybe this -- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/04/entry_469.html -- would help?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.2, Swagger can parse Jackson annotations on its own. I confirmed this using Jackson 2.1.